# Cannot resolve symbol Android annotation

Tags: android, androidx

When I inpsect class to add color to NumberPicker widget, I found that these annotatioin is missing in libraries. My app works well but I am trying to investigate more in source code.
Can I do something to add missing part here?

I already have setting in gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

[image]